# How can this argument be made more rigorous?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, real-numbers

I'm reading a book on Real Analysis, and i can't understand an argument on the proof of the subadditivity of the Lebesgue outer measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$. We want to show that if $E = \cup_{j=1}^\infty E_j$ then we have $m^* \left( E \right) \leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty m^{*} (E_j)$. Now, as usual, we use the Zeno trick. Fix $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and notice that for each positive integer $j$ there is a covering $E_j \subseteq \cup_{k=1}^\infty Q_{j, k}$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |Q_{j, k}| \leq m^{*} (E_j) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2^j}$. Then we get $m^{*} (E) \leq \sum_{j, k} |Q_{j, k}| = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty |Q_{j, k}| \leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty m^{*} (E_j) + \varepsilon / 2^j = \varepsilon + \sum_{j=1}^\infty m^{*} (E_j)$. And so, because $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, the result is proven. Problem is, i don't know how to justify this step:  $\sum_{j, k} |Q_{j, k}| = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty |Q_{j, k}|$.

Comment: I recommend to look at this paper about double sequences and series. If I'm not mistaken, theorem $8.6$ is exactly what you need: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242705642_Double_Sequences_and_Double_Series

Comment: For non-negative $a_i \in \Bbb{R}$, the notation $\sum_{i \in I} a_i$ makes sense for any index set $I$: it just means the supremum (if it exists) of $\sum_{i \in J}a_i$, where $J$ ranges over finite subsets of $I$. If $I$ happens to be $\Bbb{N^+} \times \Bbb{N^+}$ it doesn't make any difference how you order the summands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible definition for a double sum is

$$
\sum_{j,k\in \mathbb{N}}a_{j,k}:=\lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^na_{j,k}\tag1
$$
Then for non-negative $a_{j,k}$ you have that

$$
\sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{k=0}^na_{j,k}\leqslant \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{j,k}\tag2
$$

as $\sum_{k=1}^n a_{j,k}\leqslant \sum_{k=1}^{\infty }a_{j,k}$ for any chosen $j\in \mathbb{N}$ (notice that its possible that $\sum_{k= 1}^{\infty }a_{j,k}=\infty $, so the order relation is taken in the extended real line). Now assuming (1) and using (2) you have the inequality

$$
\sum_{j,k\in \mathbb{N}}a_{j,k}\leqslant \sum_{j=1}^{\infty }\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }a_{j,k}\tag3
$$

what is all that you need to be sure about the proof of the subadditivity of the Lebesgue outer measure.

---

EDIT: the above is not accurate. It depends on the meaning of the expression $\sum_{j,k\in \mathbb{N}}a_{j,k}$. Generally the meaning is not (1), its something more involved named an *unordered sum*, what is defined as

$$
\sum_{j,k\in\mathbb{N}}a_{j,k}:=\sum_{(j,k)\in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}}a_{j,k}:=\sup_{I\subset \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}: |I|<\aleph _0}\sum_{(j,k)\in I}a_{j,k}\tag4
$$

(usually defined for non-negative $a_{j,k}$ or other more complex objects as series in Hilbert spaces.) Now, as to the supremum stated in (4) there is an increasing sequence of finite subsets $\{I_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ such that

$$
\sup_{I\subset \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}: |I|<\aleph _0}\sum_{(j,k)\in I}a_{j,k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{(j,k)\in I_n}a_{j,k}\tag5
$$

and as every $I_n\subset \{1,\ldots ,K_n\}\times \{1,\ldots ,K_n\}$ for some $K_n\in \mathbb{N}$, then we have that

$$
\sum_{(j,k)\in I_n}a_{j,k}\leqslant \sum_{j=1}^{K_n}\sum_{k=1}^{K_n}a_{j,k}\\
\implies \sup_{I\subset \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}: |I|<\aleph _0}\sum_{(j,k)\in I}a_{j,k}\leqslant \sum_{j=1}^{\infty }\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }a_{j,k}\tag6
$$

So nothing is lost and we get again the same inequality.

Answer (score 1):

If $a_{jk} \in [0, \infty]$, we have
$$\sum_{(j, k) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}}a_{jk} = \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}a_{jk}.$$
The proof is elementary and can be found here (Theorem 0.0.2): [http://www.stat.rice.edu/~dobelman/courses/texts/qualify/Measure.Theory.Tao.pdf](http://www.stat.rice.edu/%7Edobelman/courses/texts/qualify/Measure.Theory.Tao.pdf)